# How do I determine the path to Applications within "Open with" context menu on OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

I've got several versions of the Flash Player listed in my "Open with" context menu.  I'd like to determine the path to those applications.  I'd also like greater control over those items in the list.  How can I determine the path to and change the path to Applications listed in teh "Open with" menu?

[image: Open with menu]

Answer (score 4):

Select one of them and when the application opens click and hold on it in the dock. In the options menu select Show in Finder and that will point you to the path of the application.

To associate an application with certain files select Other in the Open With menu. When you select the application there is a checkbox for Always Open With.